# What was the difference between "that" and "which" one hundred years ago?

Tags: meaning

I understand that today "that" opens restrictive clauses and "which" does not open one. However, I have seen "which" used in older works where follows a clearly restrictive clause.

For instance,

“That is a question which Mr. Darcy only can answer.”

"The disasters which befel Jones on his departure for Coventry; ..."

What was then the difference between the two words?

Comment: You understand incorrectly. _Which_ (or _who_) can introduce restrictive relative clauses, and so can _that_. Only _wh_-words can introduce non-restrictive relative clauses, however. Whoever told you that zombie rule did not understand English grammar, but was just passing on what they were taught incorrectly, too.

Comment: It's not just in older works. Many speakers today use "which" restrictively. A pattern that actually is rarely seen nowadays and used to be somewhat common is using "that" in non-restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: Further evidence comes from Franklin D Roosevelt's quote about the day of the 1941 Pearl Harbour attack: "a date which will live in infamy". Going further back, the King James Bible, 1611: "Render therefore unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's".

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2011/12/23/which-hunting/) blog post for the history of this "rule".

Answer (score 1):

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS16) ends 6.22 with this:

> Although *which* can be substituted for *that* in a restrictive clause (a
>   common practice in British English), many writers preserve the
>   distinction between restrictive *that* (with no commas) and
>   nonrestrictive *which* (with commas). See also 5.220 under *that; which.*

Bryan Garner [says](https://www.google.ca/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22It+enhances+clarity.+And+the+best+American+editors+follow+it%22) of the distinction: “It enhances clarity. And the best American editors follow it.”

If you follow the link above and click through to the cited passage – and maybe go up a bit – you can see that Garner is clearly not happy with how “British writers have utterly bollixed the distinction between restrictive and nonrestrictive relative pronouns.”

Back to CMOS16:

> In British English, writers and editors seldom observe the distinction
>   between the two words. See also 6.22.

That was from 5.220 under *that; which.*

The question is: What is the difference between the two words?

For the usage at issue, in general there is no difference. But in “polished American prose” (CMOS16/5.220) – there is.

That said, check out [*Which* Hunting](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2011/12/23/which-hunting/) – thanks to @PeterShor for the reference – especially this:

> In my research for my thesis, I’ve found that changing “which” to
>   “that” is the single most frequent usage change that copy editors
>   make. If so many writers either don’t know the rule or can’t apply it
>   consistently, it stands to reason that most readers don’t know it
>   either and thus won’t notice the difference. Some editors and
>   grammarians might take this as a challenge to better educate the
>   populace on the alleged usefulness of the rule, but I take it as
>   evidence that it’s just not useful.

In other words, copy editors apply the so-called rule consistently to make sure “polished American prose” is what gets published. Almost no one else notices. Or cares much if they do.

Answer (score 1):

[This 1888 grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=TakyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA363&dq=pronouns+which+that&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj93d7UmPLSAhWD44MKHbBrCnIQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=pronouns%20which%20that&f=false) at Google books makes no mention of restrictive versus nonrestructive clauses in its discussion of relative pronouns. And in fact, it gives as an examples several sentences where *which* heads a restrictive clause, e.g.,

> Letters which are improperly addressed go to the dead-letter office.

The only difference between *which/who/whom* and *that* it gives is:

> Use *that* (rather than *who* or *which*) after a superlative expression.

So you shouldn't say **the greatest man who ever lived*; you need to use *that* and not *who*.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greatest+man+that%2Cgreatest+man+who+%2B+greatest+man+whom&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20man%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28greatest%20man%20who%20%2B%20greatest%20man%20whom%29%3B%2Cc0) shows some support for this rule in 19th century usage.